# First derivative test and uniqueness of local extrema

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, proof-writing

This is the context in which my question lies. See below for the actual question. Let  $f(x)$ be  differentiable everywhere and have a minimum at $x^*$.  Then for every $x$ in a proper neighbourhood of $x^*$:

$$
\left| \frac{f(x)-f(x^*)}{x-x^*}  -f'(x^*)  \right|   < \epsilon \in \mathbb{R^{++}}
$$

If $f'(x^*) \neq 0$, we may set  $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}  \left| f'(x^*) \right| $ and so:

\begin{align}
&\left| \frac{f(x)-f(x^*)}{x-x^*}  -f'(x^*) \right|  < \frac{1}{2} \left| f'(x^*) \right| \notag\\
& f'(x^*)-\frac{1}{2}\left| f'(x^*) \right|  <  \frac{f(x)-f(x^*)}{x-x^*} < f'(x^*)+\frac{1}{2}\left| f'(x^*)\right|  \tag{*}\label{*}
\end{align}

If we assume $f'(x^*)>0$, the first inequality in the last line of \eqref{*}, brings:

$$\frac{f(x)-f(x^*)}{x-x^*}  > f'(x^*)-\frac{1}{2} f'(x^*) >0$$

which, for $x<x^*$, contrasts with $x^*$ being a minimum.

If we assume $f'(x^*)<0$, the first inequality in the last line of \eqref{*}, brings:

$$
 \frac{f(x)-f(x^*)}{x-x^*} < f'(x^*) - \frac{1}{2} f'(x^*) <0
$$

which, for $x>x^*$, again contrasts with $x^*$ being a minimum.

Therefore, to get a minimum, it is necessary that $f'(x^*)=0$ (and one can prove the same for a maximum with "symmetric" reasoning).

> I think that, given the assumptions for $f$, I could  rework these lines to  prove  that a local extrema is unique in a proper neighbourhood when the condition $f'(x^*)=0$ is met. Is it possible to deal with uniqueness along these lines without recalling other theorems? In particular, if the statement is false, is there is a related, true, statement?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are wrong. A vanishing derivative only tells you have found a stationary point. Just consider $f(x)=x^3$ for $x=0$.

If $f(x)$ is convex, then $f'(x)=0$ implies a local minima but not its unicity, think about $f(x)= c$, with $c$ any constant.

For a (local) minimum to be unique you need the positive semidefinitness of the Hessian matrix, ore in one dimension a strictly positive second derivative.

Comment: I don't get you. I wrote: "[...] to get a minimum, it is *necessary* that $f'(x^*)=0$ [...]", not *sufficient*. As for the uniqueness of the local extremum, the assumption is that we do have a minimum (or a maximum), but we don't know if it is unique.

Comment: Well I read ".. prove that a local extrema is unique in a proper neighbourhood when the condition f′(x∗)=0 is met." In my understanding that mean that $f'(x^*)=0$ implies unicity. That is not true.

Comment: "rework these lines to prove [...]", without changing the assumptions, i.e. "Let $f(x)$ be differentiable everywhere and have a minimum at $x^∗$.", but I will make it more explicit.